# Android Error implementing image on click listener in listview

Tags: android

Hi there I am new to Android Programming

I have successfully created a listview application
In each listview, there is an image on the Left hand side and text on the Right side of the screen

What I am trying to achieve:
When the user click on the image, it would link him to another page
Error: I encounter error doing so even though I am using an interface

My Code is below 
Please help me out:

```
 public interface OnImageClickListener {
   public void onClick(View view); // Object data [Optional]
 }
```

CustomListViewAndroidExample.java

```
   public class CustomListViewAndroidExample extends Activity implements  

   OnImageClickListener {
      ....More code
      public void onClick(View view) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Intent intent = new  

            Intent(getApplicationContext(),SingleLockerActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
   }
```

CustomAdapter.java

```
  public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter   implements OnClickListener {

     public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View vi=convertView;
    ViewHolder holder;

    if(convertView==null){ 


        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tabitem, null); 

        /******** View Holder Object to contain tabitem.xml file elements ************/
        holder=new ViewHolder();
        holder.text=(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.text);
        holder.text1=(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.text1);
        holder.image=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.image);

       /************  Set holder with LayoutInflater ************/
        vi.setTag(holder);
    }
    else  
        holder=(ViewHolder)vi.getTag();

    if(data.size()<=0)
    {
        holder.text.setText("No Data");

    }
    else
    {
        /***** Get each Model object from Arraylist ********/
        tempValues=null;
        tempValues = (ListModel) data.get(position);

        /************  Set Model values in Holder elements ***********/
         holder.text.setText(tempValues.getCompanyName());
         holder.text1.setText(tempValues.getUrl());


              holder.image.setImageResource(res.getIdentifier
              ("com.example.customlistview24:drawable
              /"+tempValues.getImage(),null,null));


         vi.setOnClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(position));
         }
        //Gabriel Code 28/01/2014
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.image);
        imageView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            Log.v("23455", "12355");
            try {

                mListener = new CustomListViewAndroidExample();
            } catch (ClassCastException e) {
                throw new 
                            ClassCastException(activity.toString() + "  
                            must implement OnFileSelectedListener");
            }

            if (mListener != null) {
                Log.v("234", "123");
                //mListener.onClick(v);


            }

        }


    });


             return vi;
           }

            }
```

The error lies in CustomAdapter.java
in this line:

```
   mListener = new CustomListViewAndroidExample();
    logcat:java.lang.nullpointerException
```

Please help me out, I read up on many other stackoverflow articles, but i am still stuck

```
CustomListViewAndroidExample
public class CustomListViewAndroidExample extends Activity implements OnImageClickListener {

ListView list;
CustomAdapter adapter;
public  CustomListViewAndroidExample CustomListView = null;
public  ArrayList<ListModel> CustomListViewValuesArr = new ArrayList<ListModel>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_custom_list_view_android_example);

    CustomListView = this;

    setListData();

    Resources res =getResources(); 
            list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);

             /**************** Create Custom Adapter *********/
             adapter=new CustomAdapter(CustomListView, CustomListViewValuesArr,res);
               list.setAdapter(adapter);

          }

            /****** Function to set data in ArrayList *************/
                  public void setListData()
                 {

          for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {

        final ListModel sched = new ListModel();

          /******* Firstly take data in model object ******/
           sched.setCompanyName("Company "+i);
           sched.setImage("image"+i);
           sched.setUrl("http:\\\\www."+i+".com");

        /******** Take Model Object in ArrayList **********/
        CustomListViewValuesArr.add(sched);
        }

                }

              public void onItemClick(int mPosition)
              {
                 ListModel tempValues = (ListModel) 

                CustomListViewValuesArr.get(mPosition);

                  Toast.makeText(CustomListView, 
            ""+tempValues.getCompanyName()+" \nImage:"+tempValues.getImage()+" 

                    \nUrl:"+tempValues.getUrl(), 
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                      .show();
                    }

    @Override
     public void onClick(View view) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Intent intent = new                     

             Intent(getApplicationContext(),SingleLockerActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
       }


          }
```

Comment: post the full logcat stack  trace

Comment: 01-28 21:00:58.250: E/AndroidRuntime(7281): FATAL EXCEPTION: main



01-28 21:00:58.250: E/AndroidRuntime(7281): java.lang.NullPointerException


01-28 21:00:58.250: E/AndroidRuntime(7281):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.getApplicationContext(ContextWrapper.java:101)


01-28 21:00:58.250: E/AndroidRuntime(7281):  at com.example.customlistview24.CustomListViewAndroidExample.onClick(CustomListViewAndroidExample.java:72)


01-28 21:00:58.250: E/AndroidRuntime(7281):  at com.example.customlistview24.CustomAdapter$1.onClick(CustomAdapter.java:129)

Answer (score 0):

#### In mListener= new CustomListViewAndroidExample();

why will your mListener not be null?(please paste the relevant code) and from CustomListViewAndroidExample **Activity** ?

Comment: i am not sure if you are using CustomAdapter properly, please refer: (http://www.milesburton.com/Android_-_Building_a_ListView_with_an_OnClick_Position)